# How can i make an addition in excel?

Tags: excel, addition

How can i make the following calculation? See screenshot column "C".

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: How is this about programming? Please do some research before posting. Research what the site is about and research how to enter a simple Excel formulas.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear but I suppose you mean how to make addition of the all cells earlier..?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The following picture shows the answer:

[image: Excel Addition]

Comment: Although that is "correct" in terms of "it will work" it's not a efficient solution. With let's say 1000 lines of numbers this solution is way too inefficient so I suggest you study a bit how arrays and SUM() works in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is you can achieve the functionality by using `SUM()` function - place the `=SUM($B$1:B1)` to cell C1, then copy down.

[image: Example, use your own reference]